# Integration using substitution question?

Tags: integration

I'm supposed to use the substitution $x=\pi -t$ to show that

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi }xf(\sin x)dx=\frac{1}2{}\pi \int_{0}^{\pi }f(\sin x)dx
$$

but in this you use that

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi }xf(\sin x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi }tf(\sin t)dt
$$

and that

$$
\frac{1}2{}\pi \int_{0}^{\pi }f(\sin x)dx=\frac{1}2{}\pi \int_{0}^{\pi }f(\sin t)dt
$$

and I am not sure why the two equations above hold. I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious, but considering $x=\pi-t$ why are $x$ and $t$ the same here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: x and t are just dummy variables

Comment: Thank you Abstraction- I think I get it now. It doesn't really matter what x and t are...

Answer (score 1):

$x=\pi-t\implies dx=-dt$

$$I=\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx=-\int_\pi^0(\pi-t)f(\sin(\pi-t)) dt$$

$$=\int_0^\pi(\pi-t)f(\sin t) dt\text{ as }\int_a^b f(x)dx=-\int_b^a f(x)dx$$

$$=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin t) dt- \int_0^\pi tf(\sin t) dt$$

$$\implies I=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin t) dt- I$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^\pi xf(\sin(x)) dx
= \int_0^{\pi/2} xf(\sin(x)) dx
+ 
\int_{\pi/2}^\pi xf(\sin(x)) dx
$$

Now take $u=\pi-x$ in the integral:
$$
\int_{0}^\pi xf(\sin(x)) dx
= \int_{0}^\pi (\pi - u)f(\sin(\pi - u))du
\\
= \int_{0}^\pi (\pi - u)f(\sin(u))du
\\
= \int_{0}^\pi \pi f(\sin(u))du
- \int_{0}^\pi u f(\sin(u))du
$$hence
$$
\int_{0}^\pi u f(\sin(u))du
= \frac \pi2 \int_{0}^\pi f(\sin(u))du
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply mookid, but I'm still unsure. If you use the substitution $x=\pi-t$ then the second line (in my question) has ($\pi$-t)f(sint) rather than xf(sinx), and has the integral limits swapped. So unless the integral of $\pif(sint)$ with lower limit $\pi$ and upper limit 0 is equal to zero, I can't see how they would be equivalent...

Comment: you have to change t int hte sin function and in front of f.

Comment: I think I get it now, but I have a quick final question: Can you also say that $\int xf(sinx)dx= \int tf(sint)dx$ (i.e. when there are no limits of integration)? My guess is no because the constant could be different?

Comment: no, you can't. because $\int g(t) dx $ depends on $t$ while $\int g(x)dx$ does not.

Comment: Oh, sorry- I meant $\int xf(sinx)dx= \int tf(sint)dt$...

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\pi x \>f(\sin x)\ dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \bigl(x+(\pi -x)\bigr) \>f(\sin x)\ dx=\pi \int_0^{\pi/2} f(\sin x)\ dx\ .$$